# What do you call this kind of wrinkles on clothes for decoration?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

On some clothes, there are added wrinkle details for decoration, like in the picture below.

[image]

What do you call this kind of wrinkles on clothes for decoration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**frill**](https://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/frill-0) •  /fril/ • noun
a strip of gathered or pleated material sewn by one side onto a garment or larger piece of material as a decorative edging or ornament.

Synonyms and near-synonyms include **ruffle, flounce, ruff, furbelow, jabot, peplum, flute, ruche, ruching, gather, tuck, fringe, purfle, pleat,...**

Comment: Related: [pleat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pleat) ? Or not really?

Comment: Duly added, ty! (***near-*** synonym! :)

Comment: (I'd *seen* the word ***furbelow*** before, but I just assumed it was a facetious name for a type of [***merkin***](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/merkin) until it turned up in my googled "synonyms" list here! :)

Comment: **Pleats** are sharp creases pressed into a skirt, not the loose unstructured frill shown here. (When I read the title, I was expecting the picture to show a pleated garment.) A jabot is attached at the throat and a peplum round the waist.

Comment: @KateBunting: As I recall, ***pleat*** did cross my mind when I *started* my answer - but I knew that wouldn't be the "right" answer because, as you say, pleats are usually *sharp* creases, and OP specified ***wrinkles***. I would have included it in my list of "and near-synonyms" without BCLC's prompting, if I'd consciously noticed it wasn't in the list as copied from the first thesaurus site I found. But I'm sure there are more terms, and I don't suppose *all* them have clear non-overlapping definitions even to professional couturiers...

Comment: ...and let's not forget [Upstart Crow's](https://www.maturetimes.co.uk/robert-tanitch-reviews-the-upstart-crow/) legendary "**puffling pants**". (They're more "balloony" than "creased" or "wrinkly"! :)